# What is inherited from the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Taken from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

What is inherited from the base class?
In principle, a derived class inherits every member of a base class except:

```
its constructor and its destructor
its operator=() members
its friends
```

My question is, what are operator=() members?

Comment: Trying to rationalise the rubbish cplusplus.com spews is a fool's errand! Buy [a good book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define any kind of operator=(). Even very useless ones. But non of them will be inherited to the child class. From your link site I changed the example a little to make it more clear. This example won't compile because of the mentioned errors.

```
class mother {
public:
    mother ()
    { cout << "mother: no parameters\n"; }
    explicit mother (int a):m_int(a)
    { cout << "mother: int parameter\n"; }

    mother& operator=(mother const& rhs)
    {
        if(&rhs != this)
        {
            m_int = rhs.m_int;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    mother& operator=(int i)
    {
        m_int = i;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    int m_int;
};

class son : public mother {
public:
    explicit  son (int a) : mother (a)
    { cout << "son: int parameter\n\n"; }
};
int main()
{
    mother mom(2);
    son daniel(0);
    mom = 3;
    daniel = 4; // compile error
    daniel = mom; // also error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`operator=()` is the assignment operator. By having the plural on "members", it means all assignment operator overloads (e.g. `+=`, `*=`, etc.).

Comment: I suspect the plural may also mean multiple overloads of `operator=`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the list is only partially correct for C++98. In C++98 constructors are not inherited (while `operator=` is inherited, but automatically shadowed). In C++11 one must distinguish between ordinary inheritance, which does not include constructors, and explicit constructor inheritance via `using`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be the assignment operator `Object& operator=(const Object& rhs)` and the transfer operator `Object& operator=(Object& rhs)`, as seen with smart pointers etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `operator=()` is the classes assignment operator, and it is defined if you want to be able to easily assign values form one object of your class to another without having to tediously step through the porcess every single time. The process is called `overloading`, and Wikipedia has a [great article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) covering the topic, as does the [C++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/).